# Using Core's DI Singleton as a memory data provider?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-core

I need to get a list of stations(lazily) from a remote service and to store it in DB and in memory.
Then, if someone wants the list, he tries to read the in memory list.
If it's null , it goes to Db  and if there's no data in DB , it should go to a remote service  , fetch the list , and to  store the list in DB and in memory.

*(Basically, I don't want to go to the remote service every request)*

So I've used the .net core's singleton service :

`services.AddSingleton<IStations,Stations>()`

Where the class will contain the list itself :

```
public class Stations:IStations
{
 public List<StationModel> LstStationModel
        {
            get
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    if (_lstStationModel == null)

                    {
                        var ls = GetStationsFromDb().Result;
                        if (ls!=null && ls.Count > 0)
                            _lstStationModel = ls;
                        else
                            _lstStationModel = GetStationsFromProvider().Result;

                    }
                    return _lstStationModel;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    _lstStationModel = value;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

So now I have a single property in a singleton class .
When someone asks for the list , I check if it's null , then I go to db. 
If the db doesn't have the data , I start fetching from remote and fill the list.

I've also added lock , so that 2 requests won't invoke fetching twice.

**Question**

Something here doesn't look right.I'm not sure it's the right way of dong it. And besides , I really don't like this solution.

Is there any way to do it in a more elegant/better way ?

Comment: You can't if you don't prefer to hack your way around it. SO already have questions & answers related to "async properties".

Comment: @mikko I already know that props cant be used with async. It's just that this whole approach seems bad to me

Comment: Then just convert to get/set methods that provide same functionality? Or maybe I'm missing something else here?

Comment: When should the list be updated?  Why bother downloading the list if you are just going to put it in the database? Just put it in the database to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8) for that intent. If you pass true in the constructor it indicates it is thread-safe.
Example:

```
 public class Stations : IStations
    {
        Lazy<List<StationModel>> _lazyStation = new Lazy<List<StationModel>>(() => Provider.GetStationsFromProvider().Result, isThreadSafe: true);

        public List<StationModel> LstStationModel
        {
            get { return _lazyStation.Value; }
            set { _lazyStation = new Lazy<List<StationModel>>(() => value, isThreadSafe: true);  }
        }

    }
```

Note that this wouldn't be the best solution for caching or accessing data because you are coupling your Provider to the Stations object. I'd recommend creating a service/class and inject your "Provider" (as an abstraction) into it in order to invert the dependency ([Dependency Inversion Principle](https://stackify.com/dependency-inversion-principle/)). If you will create a Service/Manager class you could even inject a ICacheService and implement it using [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8)